# Guice + Quartz + iBatis

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, ibatis, guice

I'm trying to wire together Guice (Java), Quartz scheduler and iBatis ([iBaGuice](http://code.google.com/p/ibaguice/)) to do the following:

1. Start command line utility-scanner using `main()`
2. Periodically scan directory (provided as argument) for files containing formatted output (XML or YAML)
3. When file is detected, parse and output result to the database

The problems:

1. I used [this example](http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2009/01/quartz-fits/) to wire Guice and Quartz. However I'm missing some important details which I'm asking in the comments but the post is somewhat dated so I'm quoting it here also:

> 1. It's not obvious how to set-up the scheduler. Where and how would I wire the `Trigger` (I can use `Trigger#makeMinutelyTrigger`)?
> 2. I really have just one type of job I will be executing, I understand that details in the JobFactory#newJob are coming from the `TriggerFiredBundle` parameter but where/how do I wire that? And where/how do I create or wire concrete Job?

P.S. I got a little bit further by creating and wiring ScheduleProvider. Now I'm stuck with how to actually schedule the Job in this following snippet. It seams that my `JobFactory#newJob` method is never called

```
public class CollectorServiceImpl implements CollectorService {
Scheduler scheduler;

/**
 * @throws SchedulerException
 */
@Inject
public CollectorServiceImpl(final SchedulerFactory factory, final GuiceJobFactory jobFactory)
        throws SchedulerException {
    scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
    scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
}

/**
 * @throws SchedulerException
 * @see teradata.quantum.reporting.collector.service.CollectorService#start()
 */
@Override
public void start() throws SchedulerException {
    Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeMinutelyTrigger("MIN_TRIGGER");
    scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger); // this fails trigger validation since no job name is provided
    scheduler.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

core to your problem is, you don´t actually schedule a job class:

```
getScheduler().scheduleJob(new JobDetail("myFooJob", null, FooJob.class),
        TriggerUtils.makeMinutelyTrigger("MIN_TRIGGER"));
```

full answer & demo code on http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2009/01/quartz-fits/

Comment: Thank you Uwe - this is exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need scheduling, or just execution of repeating tasks at fixed intervals?
If the later, have a look at java build in ExecutorService, especially the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. Saves a whole framework for something quite simple :)

Comment: This is a first step. I really need cron-type scheduler in the nearest future and Quartz fits the bill